# settings.database is improperly configured when using Amazon RDS postgres database

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, django-admin, amazon-rds

I am using Django and when i load this code it works when signing into the admin login. However when proceeding after logging in it comes up with the database being improperly configured please specify engine value. I have added an else statement and have tried using a local database with it. But it comes up with a 500 http error whenever i add in the local database. Thanks for the help!

```
if 'database' in os.environ:

DATABASES = {
 'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': os.environ['database'],
     'USER': os.environ['datauser'],
     'PASSWORD': os.environ['data!aa'],
    'HOST': os.environ['xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'],
     'PORT': os.environ['xxxx'],
    }
}
```

I am also using mac(osx)

Comment: name, user and password are all using the same value... are you sure this is correct? And are you sure this env variable is set in AWS?

Comment: @lucasnadalutti these are fake values they all are different in my code. I know this code works with aws as it works on the admin panel. The only issue is after logging into it i get it being improperly configured.

Comment: Got it. I guess you should SSH to the instance where you deployed your code to and check if all these env variables are really set and have the values you expect. This is the problem in most cases.

Comment: @lucasnadalutti any idea on how i would do so , i am new to using this

Comment: Check here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

When you're in your instance, use `printenv {ENVVAR}` to check if your env variable is properly set (e.g. `printenv database`)

Comment: @lucasnadalutti hi i have connected it, but it doesnt sort out the error as it is to do with django and how its formatted i  think . it comes up with this : ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/login/
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

Comment: Thing is you use several env variables (which are accessed in Python via the `os.environ` dict) which might not be properly configured in your environment. So, suppose your database name is `mydb`. You expect `os.environ['database']` to give you `mydb`, but if you do `printenv database` inside your instance and this returns you nothing, it will indicate that your environment variables are not set.

Comment: okay so how would i be able to solve this problem? thanks ! @lucasnadalutti